# .NET Click Once Deployment App.config

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce, app-config

I am using VS2008 SP1 ClickOnce Deployment to deploy an application. The application references a web service which stores connection details in the app.config file. For example, the following is stored:

```
<client>
 <endpoint address="http://someservice.com/someservice" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoapBinding" contract="AService.AService" name="AServicePort"  behaviorConfiguration="endPointBehavior"/>
</client>
```

I need to be able to verify the value of this end point address on the deployed application. I have full access each of the deployed files on the server but I don't see a reference to any of the app.config entries.

Where are app.config settings stored in the published data and how can I access them?

Kind Regards,
F.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Application settings consumes two files: app.exe.config and
>   user.config, where app is the name of your Windows Forms application.
>   user.config is created on the client the first time your application
>   stores user-scoped settings. app.exe.config, by contrast, will exist
>   prior to deployment if you define default values for settings. Visual
>   Studio will include this file automatically when you use its Publish
>   command. If you create your ClickOnce application using Mage.exe or
>   MageUI.exe, you must make sure this file is included with your
>   application's other files when you populate your application manifest.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228995.aspx)

It's name is `app.exe.config.deploy` and its located in the top folder where you deploy under the Application Files folder under the version folder.

For example if your app is deployed to "`C:\App`" then it will be located on "`C:\App\Application Files\DirectoryPerVersion\ProjectName.exe.config.deploy`"